# Preg_match_all несколько вхождений

Tags: php

пытаюсь распарсить html страницу.
на странице несколько тегов вида

```
<div class="directlink" ...
<div class="directlink" ...
<div class="directlink" ...
```

в результате preg_match_all я получаю данные только из первой строчки... почему?

Comment: Не видя php-кода и html судить сложно. Может Вы парсите только первую строку и не смотрите остальные...

Comment: Раз предмет разговора регулярное выражение- стоит огласить его. У меня хрустальный шар закатился куда-то - не смогу протелепатировать.

Answer (score 1):

Не надо использовать регулярки для парсинга html.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454
- http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/